# Recent Changes in Objective-C runtime/ Xcode 4.2 code

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcode4.2

I've just started learning Obj-C and i'm a little confused. The videos I've been watching on Lynda.com were created with Xcode 4, but there are so many differences that I find it hard to believe that all of them occurred in 2 point releases. For instance:

In the video you could write:

```
@property NSString * myString
```

And it would be fine, but now in 4.2 it throws an error unless you write something like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * myString
```

In addition, there are no longer init or dealloc methods in the implementation code by default and NSAutoReleasePool is implemented completely differently.  What gives?

Comment: Please show the error you see.  The former property declaration works fine on my 4.2 install.

Comment: It could be compiler settings. Im working on a foundation project where I haven't changed anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't guarantee that this list is exhaustive, the differences you'll find on the net are:

- Objective-C 1.0 or 2.0
- Old or modern runtime
- Manual or automatic reference counting

My personal take on the main differences is:

- Objective-C 2.0 brought properties and synthesized accessors among other things
- The modern runtime has a different way of organizing instance variables (non-fragile instance variables), but you probably won't notice in day-to-day development work
- The modern runtime also allows 64-bit apps if the OS supports it
- Automatic reference counting lets you do away with retain/release code at the modest cost of following the coding and naming conventions

There are more differences, but these are the most important ones as I see it - personally I rarely have to use autorelease pools, and if I understand correctly the new syntax does not change the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a project with "automatic reference counting" option "on" then there wouldn't be any init or dealoc methods.

Answer (score 1):

When creating project
CHECK the Use **Automatic Reference Counting**.
[image]

Comment: is arc the only new thing or is there more I should read about?

Answer (score 1):

When creating a project you can check the option "Use Automatic Reference Counting". If you do check this, then there won't be any init or dealloc methods, because Xcode automatically does the reference counting.

Comment: You still write -initXXX methods with ARC for the same cases you would have written one before. (And you may still write -dealloc methods also, but less often probably)